# tcolorbox locally change color of text in a code block

Tags: color, listings, tcolorbox, minted, code

I've been working with `\tcolorbox` for a bit to get the desired output of my code blocks, *see* below for an example:
[image]

and code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, minted, xparse, breakable, skins}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{\scriptsize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newtcblisting[
        blend into=listings
    ]{bash}[2][]{%
        title=#2,
        breakable,
        listing only,
        detach title,
        coltitle=black,
        listing engine=minted,
        comment above* listing,
        comment=\raggedright\tcbtitle,
        minted language=bash,
        minted style=stata-light, colback=gray!10, beamer, frame hidden,
        minted options={fontsize=\footnotesize, tabsize=2, breaklines, autogobble,
        linenos, numbersep=5pt, frame=lines, framesep=2mm, baselinestretch=1.2, breakanywhere},
        overlay={
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!90] (frame.south west)
        rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}
        },
        blend before title code={},
        #1
    }
}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=electricultramarine,
    filecolor=.,
    linkcolor=maroon,
    urlcolor=smokyblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.69, 0.19, 0.38}

\begin{document}


\begin{bash}[label=listing:symmetric_graph]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\linespread{1}\selectfont\normalfont The \texttt{PGGB 0.4.0} pipeline for symmetric graph construction. This code was run on the Galileo100 HPC system, available at the time of the pilot project, using 48 threads.}}
# load necessary modules
module load profile/bioinf
ml bcftools/1.13
# activate the Conda environment to run the pipeline
source conda.sh
conda activate assembly_graphs
# pangenome construction with specific parametrization tuned for humans using GRCh38 for variant calling in the output VCF
pggb -i /g100_scratch/userexternal/mungaro0/pangenomes/pangenome_ref_guided_pggb-v4.fa.gz -o /g100_scratch/userexternal/mungaro0/VGS -t 48 -p 98 -s 100000 -n 12 -k 311 -O 0.03 -T 24 -G 13117, 13219 -S -m -V 'GRCh38_p14v2.0.fna.gz:#'
\end{bash}

...

\end{document}
```

However, as you can see, the `.03` in this Linux code is not highlighted in blue like the other numbers. My guessing is that `.` is treated as special character and, thus, everything after is read as text not numbers.

Still, this is a numerical parameter `0.03` which has to be passed to an algorithm and I would like it to be colored in blue like other numbers in the code block. is there any tweak around this? Local options seems to be not effective... Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome. I have these error with your code `Package minted Error: You must have pygmentize installed to use this package`

Comment: I'm using Overleaft, I guess if you're compiling separately you might need to download the package and load it. Let me know whether it works, thanks!

Comment: @AndréC You need to compile with shell-escape enabled and have the python library `pygments` installed

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz `shell-escape` has always been authorized in my compilations, so the error does not come from there. As for the `pygments library`, I have done everything I found on the internet with no results to date.

Comment: Your code could be simplified to `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[style=stata-light]{bash}
# pangenome construction
pggb -k 311 -O 0.03 -V 'GRCh38_p14v2.0.fna.gz:#'
\end{minted}
\end{document}` which already shows the problem. It seems like this should have come up before, I'll se if I can find something.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for the specification. AndréC, apologies but I'm not very experienced yet; hopefully what Sam said can help!

Comment: Note that the `fish` lexer, i.e., `minted language=fish` is a bit more consistent as it also does not color the `0` in `0.3` (and it still colors integers like `-k 311`. Maybe there are other issues with this lexer for your code, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @Marijn I see. I wish though to have all number in different color but if cannot be done I guess `fish` is a good alternative! However, what it does as a side effect is differentially coloring any bracket *e.g.* first one azure and second one red...

Comment: The example you show in this question does not have brackets - maybe you can use `fish` for this one and `bash` for other ones without decimal number arguments?

Comment: Indeed, this means I will have to create two different `tcolorbox` rules one for `fish` and the other for `bash` and use them alternatively based on the case in question. Good news is I have not many more code blocks to add and special cases shouldn't be an issue anymore (hopefully).

Comment: The [Bash lexer in pygments](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/26ffe8f472d18ed190a5ced00335682c618037d4/pygments/lexers/shell.py#L25) is the one to blame. See [this demo on pygments.org](https://pygments.org/demo/?lexer=bash&style=stata-light&formatter=tokens&code=pggb+-k+311+-O+0.03+-V+%27GRCh38_p14v2.0.fna.gz%3A%23%27). For input `0.03`, `0` is tokenized as `Literal.Number` and `.03` as `Text`, then when a formatter (`minted` calls it "style") specifies different colors for these two token types, boom

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ oh OK, I didn't know. Thanks for the explanation but as far as you know is there a solution to this? It seems we are getting to a dead end..., if that's the case the approach Marijn suggested does the job. Although I would be v. happy to see also those numbers as *number* and not *text*, I'm aware this is also very niche at least in my case and I doubt anyone in my PhD thesis will point out at that. I'm open to any potential fix though!

Comment: Indirect solution: Report it to pygments (https://github.com/pygments/pygments) or ultimately write your own or contribute better Bash lexer to pygments. VSCode extension ["Better Bash Syntax"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeff-hykin.better-shellscript-syntax) do its job very well. Don't know if it's possible to port textmate-derived grammar to a Pygments lexer.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thanks I reported it. Unfortunately, I'm not much of a coder and wouldn't be able to do so by myself. If they will ever reply on GitHub they might be able to assist with it. Thanks again to all!